# Getting error on heroku python app deployment

Tags: python, heroku, python-telegram-bot

```
2020-06-08T13:29:34.646588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2020-06-08T13:29:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-08T13:30:05.843602+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ocr101.herokuapp.com request_id=63c4ab08-9f17-43b9-8910-878cffcd1df8 fwd="157.47.254.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-08T13:30:07.174059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ocr101.herokuapp.com request_id=f357c946-e98e-41b5-84e3-a62b08ff4484 fwd="157.47.254.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Procfile**

worker: python bot.py

Comment: In your `Procfile` change `web` to `worker`. Since you are doing a telegram bot you probably don't need a port.

Answer (score 0):

```
web: python bot.py
```

would fix that, though it than gives many `heroku[router]: at=info` messages which I'm trying to figure out how to hide, i have a bot running node js code, and its not giving those info messages, so I'm sure its possible